# Json_Decode not Decoding my JSON

Tags: php, json, couchdb, decode

I am using couchDB to get a UUID so that I can send a new document to the database.

In order to get this UUID, I use a curl statement:

```
function getUUID(){
    $myCurlSubmit = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($myCurlSubmit, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:5984/_uuids');    
    curl_setopt($myCurlSubmit, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $response = curl_exec($myCurlSubmit);

    curl_close($myCurlSubmit);

    return $response;
}
```

This returns the expected result:

```
{"uuids":["af09ffd3cf4b35c2d94d1ed755000fb8"]}
```

However, the following json_decode fails:

```
print_r('No match, creating new document.');
$uuid = json_decode(trim(getUUID()));
var_dump(json_last_error());
```

The error printed is: 'int(0)'  (not in quotes.), and $uuid is a json string still.

Help appreciated Thank you!

EDIT:

```
var_dump($uuid) = int(1)
```

EDIT:
   var_dump(getUUID()) = {"uuids":["af09ffd3cf4b35c2d94d1ed755000fb8"]}\n1

Is there any reason why I would have a trailing one, and /n on my json??

EDIT:

The problem was with curl, look at the answer below!

Comment: `0 == JSON_ERROR_NONE`, which means no error has occurred.

Comment: I was able to copy/paste that JSON string into a php var and then successfully extract the `uuids` 1-item array with json_decode. I suggest you try saving `trim(getUUID())` into a temp variable to ensure that it has the value you expect before you call `json_decode()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of curl in the `getUUID()` function.

You must set [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php), otherwise `curl_exec` will just echo the result, while returning `1` (as you see).

See for example this comment in the `curl_exec` manual: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-exec.php#13020

Comment: wow. Thanks! I just finished isolating it to the curl_exec command when I saw this!